# Is there a way to install ubuntu by copying files to the disk?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, mount, usb-installation

I've tried to install ubuntu on my pen drive several times and always get the same error during installation that says "Attempt to mount a filesystem with type ext4 at '/' failed", or something like it. I've tried to work around this problem for some time, tried all possible ways to install ubuntu and the result was always the same. I wnat to know if there's a way to just copy the files from a machine with ubuntu full installed to the removable device, and then make the device bootable. Like a direct install, copy the necessary files to pen drive and make it work. Is there any way to do that ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is USB big enough(20GBs or more)?  Are you installing from a Ubuntu install USB, burned ISO to USB?  Have you tried different USBs, one might be bad?  Could use Clonezilla to copy to USB, if same size as your partition.

Comment: Take a look at unetbootin with persistent storage. That's seemingly what you're looking for. It'll do it automagically with Ubuntu and *only* Ubuntu (and **official** Ubuntu flavors).

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu or some other Linux distro in some (other) computer or booted from a live USB drive or DVD disk? Or are you only running Windows or MacOS?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do it the way you have tried and, no, it won't work to just copy files from a computer to a USB stick and make it work. There is a way to install Ubuntu (or whichever distribution you choose) but it is tricky. There is a recipe in the accepted answer on:

[How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

Be sure to follow it to the letter.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Ubuntu from Desktop to USB drive

It is quite easy to copy Ubuntu from your desktop computer to a USB drive, so that It boots both BIOS and UEFI modes.

- Start by creating a Persistent USB using **mkusb** with default settings.
- Delete partitions 4 and 5. Keep partition 1 if you want a Linux/Windows data partition.
- Confirm that there is enough empty space on the USB for your desktop's Ubuntu system partition, (/). Shrink the NTFS partition if necessary.
- Boot computer from a second Live USB.*
- Open GParted, select the internal drive, right click the system partition and select copy.
- Select the USB drive, right click the empty space and select paste.
- Run GParted, when done copy grub.cfg from the new root partition /boot/grub/ to the Partition 2 /boot/grub/, overwriting the existing grub.cfg file.
- If you plan on using the drive on your desktop. it is a good idea to use GParted to change the USB's UUID. GRUB and fstab UUIDs would also need to be updated.

*If you only have one USB, you can boot the mkusb install toram and then continue to delete it's partitions 4 and 5 and clone the desktop's system partition to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, sorry for my delay on answering. The problem really was the usb. O got a new one and things just worked out. I really appreciate the help =)